# Using Coffeescript to hide a <div> in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a list of items that I render via a call to a partial

```
render @items
```

each item is placed inside a div and has a JS 'disable' link

```
<div id="item_id_<%=item.id%>
   <%=item.name>
   <%= link_to disable_item_path(item), :remote => true %>
</div>
```

Inside the controller, I change the flag of the item in the database to False, and want to re-render the page and remove the item from the list.

I have been doing so by the following code in disable.js.coffee

> $('#items_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial =>
>   @items)) %>")

My question: I would like simply to hide the specific item DIV, and not re-render all the items on the page (why? because I think it's better coding).

**How do I do that?** I tried passing @item_id to the coffeescript, and doing something like

```
$('item_id'+@item_id).hide
```

but from reading around here it seems like it's the wrong way of doing so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To simply hide the div, put this in your `disable.js.coffee` file:

```
$("#item_id_<%= item.id %>").hide()
```

Comment: ID selectors should start with a #

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a parent `#items` div with each child `.item` class, then reference by `$('#items > .item').hide` or something like that.

At the moment you have

```
<div id="item_id_1">...</div>
<div id="item_id_2">...</div>
<div id="item_id_3">...</div>
```

And so on.

Instead, you can have:

```
<div id="items">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with CSS and how it works, can you please elaborate? How would the browser know which .item to hide?

Comment: Updated, hope it makes sense. From what you've said that should work. It's possible you may need to use the `.each` method, just see the [jQuery documentation on .each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) if so.

Comment: Yes, I can do that easily, but how then do I hide a variable item in the list (for example, the 2nd one)? what JQuery do I need to use for that?

Comment: I did the changes as Dylan suggested, and then used #$('.row').remove() - the result is that all my rows are getting removed, and a specific one like I need...

Comment: I found a way of doing so, wrapping my view with **<%= div_for(item) do %>** and in the disable.js file: **$('#<%= dom_id(@item) %>').hide()**